# How to remove Task from the share header?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am able to remove `MyTasks` and `My workflow` from the dashlet how to remove it from the header? I removed from the dashlet by editing `my-tasks.get.html.ftl`. But how to remove from the header menu. Which file should I modify. I am using 4.2e community edition

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you running?

Comment: @billerby edited in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 4.2.e uses the new Dojo based header. The share-header.get.js is the file you are looking for. Read up on Dave Drapers blog posts on the subject.

http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-1/

All the menu definitions can be found in the file share-header.lib.js

The one you want to hide has the id: HEADER_TASKS.